# IIS: 2 application pools, 1 w3p

Tags: iis

I read on some other sites that IIS creates 1 w3wp.exe process for each application pool. My server has 5 app pools, and 2 of them have an application. But in task manager I only see 1 w3wp.exe. Can anyone explain why?

[Here](http://s28.postimg.org/lpn4u2nzh/2_app_pools_1_w3p.png) is a screenshot:

Comment: The application pool start when you open a dynamic page and (by default) shutdown after 20 minutes of inactivity

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command at command prompt and you get even more info,

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list wp

Then you will see which worker processes belong to which application pools.